# Trying to enable PIN login results in a "Your organisation requires Windows Hello" error

Tags: windows-10, login

Until recently I worked for a large corporation. At some point I connected my home computer (running Windows 10 Home edition) to the work network via VPN. I always used a PIN to login.

After I retired from the corporation, I continued to use the PIN for login. However, since the last OS update (to 17134.165) I only have the option of a password.

When I try to enable PIN login, I am asked to identify myself and my old PIN is accepted but then I am asked to login to my old work network because "Your organisation requires Windows Hello", which, of course, I cannot do.

How can I enable PIN login?

Comment: What sort of connection did you have? Just a simple VPN, or something more like a provisioning profile or AD join?

Comment: Only VPN and possibly I also connected to The Exchange server. My home computer was never registered as part of the company domain

Comment: Use the Group Policy Editor: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-manage-in-organization

Comment: I cannot run gpedit.msc because my system is Windows Home. The Group Policy Editor is only available on Windows 10 Pro and higher